# Value is not replaced inside file

Tags: c

I'm creating a C program that reads shashank.txt file and replace occurrence of `"!"` with `"+"`  inside a file

output should be in same file only

shashank.txt content:

```
this is bsnl
!c practice
!
```

desired output(in same file ):

```
this is bsnl
+c practice 
+
```

my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>


#include<process.h>
int main ()
{
    // file pointer
    FILE *fp;
    int c;    

    // opening a file
    fp = fopen("shashank.txt", "r"); 

    //checking if correct file is opened or not
    if( fp == NULL ) 
    {
        printf("Error in opening file\n");
        return(-1);
    }

    while(!feof(fp)) 
    {
        //getting characterts
        c = getc(fp);

        /* replace ! with + */
        if( c == '!' ) 
        {
            // pushing + onto stream
             ungetc ('+', fp);                       
        }
        else 
        {
            //pushing c onto stream
            ungetc(c, fp); 
        }                     
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You have opened the file in read mode, so the only thing your code modifies is what it is about to read itself

Comment: Note: Do not use `while(!feof(fp))`.  Instead, `while (1) { c = getc(fp); if (c == EOF) break;`.  This will not solve the overall issue though.

Comment: if i use write mode it goes into infinite loop

Comment: You call 'ungetc' for every occasion, so you never end up the file. You put back a character back for every character you read in. That's why you have an infinite loop. Additonally `ungetc` works on the stream, and do not write back to the actual file.

Answer (score 2):

First thing you need to open the `r+` mode to read write in a Existing file.

```
fp = fopen("shashank.txt", "r+"); // Fix 1
```

Try the following changes-

```
    while((c = getc(fp))!=EOF) // Fix 2
    {

       /* replace ! with + */
       if( c == '!' )
       {
           fseek(fp,-1,SEEK_CUR); // It Moves current position indicator 1 position back
           fputc ('+', fp); // This will replace the ! with +
       }
   }
```

Comment: +1, nothing else is needed in that case. i just posted another way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here, you need to open the file in "rw" mode and your code never gets beyond the first character of the file as it always pushes back a character.
Try removing the else.

Answer (score 0):

"ungetc" pushes a character back into an input stream. The next "getc" to that stream will return the character that was pushed back.Pushing back characters does not change the file being accessed at all; ungetc only affects the stream buffer, not the file.
http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/ungetc.html

Answer (score 0):

you can make some workaround. open two files, one that you're reading and second one to write. then make a loop like following:

```
while (1) {
    c = fgetc(fp);
    if (c == EOF) {
        break;
    }
    if (c != '!') {
        fprintf(fp2,"%c",c);
    }
    else {
        fprintf(fp2,"+");
    }
}
```

so, if it's not `!`, write char from read file to file that you're writing. if it is, write `+`. then, close files, remove the old file within C program and then rename new file to the old file. 
as i said, this is a workaround and what @Sathish showed is good. just another way of solving this.